# C# HTTP request to PHP file to JSON

Tags: c#, php, http

I would like to write a class in c# which should send an HTTP request (post) to a PHP file which is on my server in order to retrieve a json object.

This is the code I've got:

```
   public void SendRequest(){
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create("url");

    // execute the request
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
        request.GetResponse();
    }
```

Is that what I need? What do you think I should change or improve? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: So where do you set the verb to POST ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post data and read the response:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
string yourPostData = "Your post data";
string sreverResponseText;

byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourPostData);
request.ContentLength = yourPostData.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
      requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);

using (response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
      using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            sreverResponseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Now what you are looking for is in `sreverResponseText`, also you can access headers from `response.Headers.ToString()`